# Can a person lie to keep something safe or hidden or to protect something which will benefit him?

Tags: halal-haram, lying

Can a person lie in order to keep something safe or hidden or to protect something which will benefit him? For example, once I was in a shameful situation with a kufar girl, and I lied to her in order not be a subject of a joke; is this ok?

Or for example, I have 1000€ and I plan to build a house and I don't want to give my money to anyone, and if someone ask me to give him or her 1€ then I say I don't have it.  Is this ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Islam is against telling lies in general. The only exception is if you think that telling the truth will put your safety, or your money, or the safety of those who you care about, in danger. Then you are allowed to lie to escape such danger.

In the case you described, I don't think you are really in any danger. You can simply say: "I can't lend you any money", which is true in your case.

Comment: So in other words, I can’t even mock Satan? “Because”, I want to mock and make fun of somebody and I know exactly to who I will to that, as a revenge and as a sign for Satan to leave me alone that I’m trying to side God, the Creator. Because, I was thinking if I would make fun and mock Iblis, probably he would get mad at me and will leave me alone, so that I can focus on siding God and to fulfill my job which He gave to me.